# How can i see the summary or aggregate values in jmeter jtl file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Am running recorded jmeter performance script (by adding summary and aggrgate listners), in non-gui mode using Maven. After running am getting .jtl file, but am not seeing the values for summary and aggregate values.

how can i see the summary or aggregate report in .jtl file, without opening Jmeter GUI.

We are planneing to run through jenkins on daily basis. Once jtl file is generated the other script has to look the values for summary / aggregate values and show it on the dashboard.

Can anybody please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Typically I set the results file int the [Summary Report Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) and select the fields I want to get back. When you run the test via non-gui (ie through Jenkins) you will get the summary results file and it should be in your workspace.

Here is my JMX file, testing some mobile APIs. [JMeter Test Plan and Results](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/16641)

[image]

Also to note is the [Generate Summary Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Generate_Summary_Results) Listener. Per the docs

> In Non-GUI mode by default a Generate Summary Results listener named "summariser" is configured,

This will not show up in the JTL but will show up in your log file and will generate lines such as

```
2015/08/28 15:14:33.305 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary =   2200 in   169s =   13.0/s Avg:    17 Min:     2 Max:  5129 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. 
In .jtl each sample response time is showing but I want to see the average response time of each transaction controller. 
Is there any way to see the average response time of each transaction controller in .jtl file?

Answer (score 0):

The values you're used to see in Aggregate Report / Summary Report listeners are being **calculated** from the following metrics:

- timestamp
- elapsed
- success
- bytes
- latency

For instance:

- Average metric is sub of "elapsed" times for all the samplers divided by samplers count.
- [Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Medians_of_particular_distributions) metric is a common statistical measurement basically 50% percentile
- 90%, 95%, 99% - are also [percentiles](http://www.statisticshowto.com/percentiles/) like median
- etc.

Depending on your skills set you can check i.e. [Calculator.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java) class code to see how JMeter calculates averages, percentiles, throughput, etc. and implement some form of postprocessor, use MS Excel, LibreOffice Calc or equivalent on .jtl CSV results file.

If you need to get these results after JMeter run the easiest option are:

**Vanilla Jmeter:**

- if you launch JMeter via [Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) or [Maven Plugin](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin) - you'll get HTML results file like:

  [image: Ant/Maven report]

For more information on configuring Ant and/or Maven integration refer above links or [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide.

**Using JMeter plugins:**

- [Console Status Logger](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConsoleStatusLogger/) - which prints quick stats information to stdout and jmeter.log file

> 0  Threads: 27/5000        Samples: 1      Latency: 5      Resp.Time: 5    Errors: 0%
>
> 1  Threads: 2350/5000      Samples: 142    Latency: 19     Resp.Time: 19   Errors: 0%
>
> 2  Threads: 4500/5000      Samples: 130    Latency: 51     Resp.Time: 51   Errors: 0%
>
> 3  Threads: 5000/5000      Samples: 153    Latency: 81     Resp.Time: 81   Errors: 0%

- [Loadosophia.org Uploader](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/LoadosophiaUploader/) - which uploads your test results to [Loadosophia.org](http://loadosophia.org/) cloud service where you can perform analysis, see graphs, charts, export report as PDF, etc.